# Argument mismatch while working with bounded type-variables

Tags: java, class, generics, types

The code has been simplified as follows:

Given two Java class files, Edge.java and Node.java, each generic class has two type parameters, N and E. The type parameters are bounded with upper bound generic type Node and Edge respectively.

Node.java:

```
public class Node<N extends Node<N, E>, E extends Edge<N, E>> {
    public void test(E edge) {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Edge.java:

```
public class Edge<N extends Node<N, E>, E extends Edge<N, E>> {
    public void m(N src) {
        src.test(this);
    }
}
```

And when I compiled the two java files, the error occurred:

```
$ javac Node.java Edge.java -Xdiags:verbose
Edge.java:3: error: method test in class Node<N#2,E#2> cannot be applied to given types;
        src.test(this);
           ^
  required: E#1
  found: Edge<N#1,E#1>
  reason: argument mismatch; Edge<N#1,E#1> cannot be converted to E#1
  where E#1,N#1,N#2,E#2 are type-variables:
    E#1 extends Edge<N#1,E#1> declared in class Edge
    N#1 extends Node<N#1,E#1> declared in class Edge
    N#2 extends Node<N#2,E#2> declared in class Node
    E#2 extends Edge<N#2,E#2> declared in class Node
1 error
```

It seems that the method `test` required an argument with type E#1. However, it also says E#1 was extended from Edge...

I have tried various way to get around this problem, but it seems that I can only get around this problem by modifying Edge.java into this:

```
public class Edge<N extends Node, E extends Edge<N, E>> {
    public void m(N src) {
        src.test(this);
    }
}
```

So one of the upper bound Node is changed to raw type. It compiles, but it gives warning:

```
$ javac Node.java Edge.java -Xlint:unchecked
Edge.java:3: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to test(E) as a member of the raw type Node
        src.test(this);
                ^
  where E,N are type-variables:
    E extends Edge<N,E> declared in class Node
    N extends Node<N,E> declared in class Node
1 warning
```

It works but then I lose the generic types, and the warning might cause future problems. So here are my three questions:

1. Why is the original Edge.java not working and output this error?
2. Why did the second Edge.java compile?
3. What is the best way to fix this?

Comment: What exactly do you try to achieve? This design is really odd.

Comment: I want a graph, composed of nodes and edges.  And I have different kinds of graphs (subtypes) but the nodes/edges used in one sub-type shouldn't be usable in the other subtype(s).

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the original Edge.java not working and output this error?

Because there's no guarantee that `Edge` has been parameterized with its own type. The following subclass would be compile without error, while violating the assumption that `this` is an `E`:

```
class EdgeImpl1 extends Edge<NodeImpl, EdgeImpl2> {}
```

More generally, Java doesn't support the concept of generic self types.

> Why did the second Edge.java compile?

Because raw types are contagious. The `test()` method of the raw `Node` type has a raw `Edge` parameter, so it will accept any `Edge` instance.

> What is the best way to fix this?

Unfortunately, there's no perfect solution. One approach is to simply cast `this` to `E`:

```
src.test((E)this);
```

This may cause a `ClassCastException` if the self type is misused, as in the above example. A safer but more verbose alternative is to declare an abstract method to return the appropriate `E` for each subclass:

```
abstract class Edge<N extends Node<N, E>, E extends Edge<N, E>> {
    public void m(N src) {
        src.test(returnThis());
    }

    protected abstract E returnThis();
}

class EdgeImpl extends Edge<NodeImpl, EdgeImpl> {
    @Override
    protected EdgeImpl returnThis() {
        return this;
    }
}
```